How to consider varying columns while creating a model
I have a monitoring service that sends out alerts. I am working on creating a model that would flag an alert if it has occurred more than 3 times in the last 1 month.
I am able to achieve this using IsolationForest and specifying which fields to consider for each alert in the model.
However, the problem I am facing is that the fields for an alert may vary.
Consider the following 2 alerts
AlertName        Date                  FQDN       DBName
Disk usage 90%   10/17/2024 00:00:000  test.com 
DB Restarted.    10/17/2024 01:00:000             db1

In the above example, if its a Disk usage 90% alert then I should use FQDN field
and if its DB Restarted I should use DBName field.
For each alert, the fields that should be used to determine if its a repeated alert varies which I have no control over.
Is it possible to develop model that would consider different columns for different alerts dynamically and I am not having to specify which column to consider for each alert type?
